# Python cryptocurrency arbitrage bot

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, cryptocurrency

I have created a simple tool that takes in a dictionary of cryptocurrencies and finds the ones with the highest % differences between exchanges. I would be grateful if someone could help me optimize this code and perhaps make it less complicated. The structure of the code is:

> ```
> for coin in data:
>     for market in coin.markets()
>         if conditions_are_met:
>            if is_highest_price:
>               high_price = new_high_price
>            if is_lowest_price:
>               low_price = new_low_price
>     coin_differences = append([coin.name, high_price-low_price])
>
> display_top_10(coin_differences)
> ```

This is the actual code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import decimal
import argparse
from operator import itemgetter

try:
    import pymarketcap
except Exception as e:
    print('Make sure to install {0} (python3 -m pip {0}.'.format(str(e).split("'")[1]))
    exit()

# arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--minimum_vol', type=float, help='Minimum Percent volume per exchange to have to count', default=1)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--pairs', nargs='*', default=[], help='Pairs the coins can be arbitraged with - default=all')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--coins_shown', type=int, default=10, help='Number of coins to show')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--exchanges', nargs='*', help='Acceptable Exchanges - default=all', default=[])
parser.add_argument('-s', '--simple', help='Toggle off errors and settings', default=False, action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-t', '--top', type=int, help='Set the number of coins to run with', default=100)
args = parser.parse_args()

# setup
cmc = pymarketcap.Pymarketcap()
info = []
count = 1
lowercase_exchanges = [x.lower() for x in args.exchanges]
all_exchanges = not bool(args.exchanges)
all_trading_pairs = not bool(args.pairs)
coin_format = '{: <25} {: >6}% {: >10} {: >15} {: <10} {: <10} {: <15} {: <5}'

if not args.simple:
    print('CURRENT SETTINGS',
          '* MINIMUM_PERCENT_VOL: {}'.format(args.minimum_vol),
          '* TRADING_PAIRS: {}'.format(args.pairs),
          '* COINS_SHOWN: {}'.format(args.coins_shown),
          '* EXCHANGES: {}'.format(lowercase_exchanges),
          '* ALL_TRADING_PAIRS: {}'.format(all_trading_pairs),
          '* ALL_EXCHANGES: {}'.format(all_exchanges),
          '* TOP: {}'.format(args.top),
          sep='\n')

# retrieve coin data
coin_data = cmc.ticker(limit=args.top)['data']

for id_, coin in coin_data.items():
    try:
        markets = cmc.markets(coin["id"])
    except Exception as e:
        markets = cmc.markets(coin["symbol"])

    best_price = 0
    best_exchange = ''
    best_pair = ''
    worst_price = 999999  # TODO is this value high enough? one day some cryptocurrencies will be worth several millions... i hope :)
    worst_exchange = ''
    worst_pair = ''
    has_markets = False
    for market in markets["markets"]:
        trades_into = market["pair"].replace(coin["symbol"],"").replace("-","").replace("/","")
        if (market['percent_volume'] >= args.minimum_vol and 
                market['updated'] and 
                (trades_into in args.pairs or all_trading_pairs) and 
                (market['source'].lower() in lowercase_exchanges or all_exchanges)
           ):
            has_markets = True
            if market['price'] >= best_price:
                best_price = market['price']
                best_exchange = market['source']
                best_pair = trades_into
            if market['price'] <= worst_price:
                worst_price = market['price']
                worst_exchange = market['source']
                worst_pair = trades_into
    if has_markets:
        info.append([coin['name'],
                     round((best_price/worst_price-1)*100,2),
                     worst_price,
                     worst_exchange,
                     worst_pair,
                     best_price,
                     best_exchange,
                     best_pair
                    ])
    elif not args.simple:
        print(coin['name'],'had no markets that fit the criteria.')

    print('[{}/{}]'.format(count, args.top),end='\r')
    count += 1

# show data
info = sorted(info, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(coin_format.format("COIN","CHANGE","BUY PRICE","BUY AT","BUY WITH","SELL PRICE","SELL AT","SELL WITH"))
for coin in info[0:args.coins_shown]:
    print(coin_format.format(*coin))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some random advice:

Consider using `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter`. It's a nice thing to use when you have so many defaults set.

I would lose the try/import/except. It's just as good to let the default failure take place. You can specify pip requirements in `requirements.txt`.

Group up your code into functions, even if they're only called once. There are many reasons for this - stack traces are improved, code folding is actually useful, and code legibility goes up.

Your explicit calls to `bool()` are no-ops. Python already treats everything as truthy/falsy.

Indexing `[0 :x]` is the same as indexing `[:x]`.